# Call Parent Activity method from Child Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have Activity A that starts Activity B. Let me start by saying that I believe that Activity A can't use "startActivityForResult()" because Activity B can replace himself for another Activity B (this means, starting another activity and finishing himself), and if that happened Activity A wouldn't be expecting a result anymore and that second Activity B couldn't pass Activity A the result.

Activity A has the instance of the Model. Is there anyway I can get access to the Model from Activity B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by adding into my MainActivity:

```
private static MainActivity main;

public static MainActivity getMain() {
    return main;
}
```

I am aware this is not a good practice.

Comment: Also using your simple solution. Looks like not good practice, but I dont see any problems with it. Any thoughts from others ?

Comment: I haven't touched Android since back then, but homerman reply looks like the best option (I was a little newbie back then). The Model should be built on its own module so you can access it from anywhere and not through Activity A exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

you should use a layer of persistence, such as:

- an internal database
- Shared Preferences
- a cloud service
- the filesystem

...to store the state of your model types. this way that state is durable across configuration changes that result in `Activity` instances being recreated by Android.

Answer (score 1):

In ActivityA You have to implements Serializable and using Intent.
Try it.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Go to Activity B
    Intent gotoActivityB = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    gotoActivityB.putExtra("ACTIVITY_A", this);
    startActivity(gotoActivityB);
}
```

In Activity B You can get Activity A from Intent

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

    // get Activity A
    if (getIntent() != null){
        AcitivityA acitivityA = (AcitivityA) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("ACTIVITY_A");
    }
}
```

Sorry for my bad english :(